# Passing props to an axios delete request

Tags: reactjs, axios

The objective is to, by pressing a button, delete the object from the database.

To do that, I have to pass the ID of the object I want to delete from the database to the axios query. But I'm stuck trying to do it.

In my opinion the problem is I am not passing the ID to erase to the query, since the query seems right to me.

File: persons.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3001/persons'


const deleteContact = (id) =>{
  const request = axios.delete('{$baseUrl}/${id}')
  request.then(response =>response.data)
  }

export default { 

  deleteContact: deleteContact,
 
}
```

The button that should call the function to delete:
File: person.js

```
import React from 'react'

const Person = ({ person, deleteContact }) => {
   
   
    return (
      <li> 
        {person.name} {person.number}  
        <button onClick={deleteContact(person.id)}>Delete {person.id} </button> 
      </li>
    )
  }

  export default Person
```

So, by pressing the button I execute the deleteContact funtion and I pass to that function the person.id so it sends the id to delete.

Here is waht's wrong.  I don't know how to make the function deleteContact.

I have tried this, but of course I am not sending any props. It's wrong and does nothing. I get the error TypeError: deleteContact is not a function.

```
 const deleteContact = (id) => {
 
}
```

The deleteContact funtion I try to implement is on the file App.js

It is something obvious I am missing here. But I can't figure out what is.
Likely something basic, but I have been stuck here for a while, as silly this may seem to be.

File: App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Person from './components/Person'
import Form from './components/Form'
import Filter from './components/Filter'

import FilterResults from './components/FilterResults'
import contactService from './services/persons'

//npm run server

const App = () => {




  //Reminder: current state, function that updates it, initial state.

  const [ newName, setNewName ] = useState('')
  const [ newNumber, setNewNumber ] = useState('')
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([])
  //Filter
  const [ filter, setFilter ] = useState('')
  
  
  //contactService is importer from /services/persons.
  //.getAll is like typing: axios.get('http://localhost:3001/persons')

  //Effect hooks used to fetch data from the server. The data fetched is saved
  //into the contacts state variable
  useEffect(() => {
    
    contactService
    .getAll()
    .then(response => {
      setContacts(response.data)
    console.log(contacts)
      
    
  })
  
  }, [])
/* 
  second parameter of useEffect is used to specify how often the effect
   is run. If the second parameter is an empty array [], 
   then the effect is only run along with the first render of 
   the component. */

  console.log('render', contacts.length, 'contacts')


  //adding new persons
  const addPerson = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    /* complete the addPerson function for creating new persons */
    const personObject = {
      name: newName,
      number: newNumber,
      //The server will create the id 
      //id: persons.length + 1,
    }

    //Adding the data to the server
    /* 
    using separate server comunication module from persons.js
     "create" instead of previous code:
    axios
    .post('http://localhost:3001/persons', personObject) 
    
    replaced by:
    
    contactService
    .create(personObject)
    */

    contactService
    //Passing personObject to create
    .create(personObject)
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
         //After concat, the fiel is set to blank again ('').
//Updating state after creating, to display created contact.
    setContacts(contacts.concat(personObject))
    setNewName('')
    setNewNumber('')
    })

  
  }
 //Delete contacts
 const deleteContact = (personObject) => {
 
}


  const handlePersonChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value)
    setNewName(event.target.value)
  }
  const handleNumberChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value)
    setNewNumber(event.target.value)
  }

  const handleFilterChange = (event) => {
    setFilter(event.target.value)
  }
 
 
  const personsToShow = filter === ''
    ? contacts
    : contacts.filter(person =>
        person.name.toLowerCase().includes(filter.toLowerCase()))
  const row_names = () => personsToShow.map(person => 
    <p key={person.name}>{person.name} {person.number} </p>
  )

 

  return (
    <div>
 <Filter value={filter} onChange={handleFilterChange} />

      <Form
      onSubmit={addPerson}
      name={{value: newName, onChange: handlePersonChange}}
      number={{value: newNumber, onChange: handleNumberChange}}
      deleteContacts={() => deleteContact()}

      />
 <h2>Numbers from database</h2>
     
   {/*   The contents of the database are stored on the variable contacts.
     I map through the array. Person.js component used.  */}
      <ul>
      {contacts.map(person => 
      //Pass all the props from person to Person.js
          <Person 
          key={person.id} 
          person={person} 
          
         
          
          />
         
        )}
      </ul>
      <h2>Filter results</h2>
      <FilterResults persons={row_names()} />

    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

The dabatbase is  hardcoded json.

file db.json

```
"persons": [

    {
      "name": "ss",
      "number": "ssssd",
      "id": 17
    },
    {
      "name": "ddd",
      "number": "6tyhhth",
      "id": 18
    },
    {
      "name": "almejas",
      "number": "1234",
      "id": 19
    },
    {
      "name": "pailo",
      "number": "244",
      "id": 20
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I can not see any server side code snippets. Where do you create something like router.delete("/person?:id") ?

Comment: I did not do that. The idea is to make an axios delete request with the object id, and that's all.

Comment: OK, it does not work like that. To send api requests you have to build an API first. You should have your own server side, made with Express for exaaple, where all possible requests like GET, POST, DELETE etc must be descriped. No route - no actions. I am pretty sure if you open developer tools in Chrome you can see 404 error response after your axios delete request. Thats exactly what happens - there is no server on localhost:3001 with route specifying how to delete person from DB.

Comment: Hello. This is an exercise from the fullstackopen course, and this should be done just with axios. I can add objects to the server just using axios, but I don't know how to make the delete. I don't know how to specify the id to delete.

For example this is somebody else's code of the exercise. I don't uderstand how he implemented the delete either, but is there.

https://github.com/inci-august/fullstackopen/tree/d6680a40d03536e20ee9537cc64e1cb57dd6b74a/part2/phonebook

Comment: I had to publish an answer because text is too long for a comment field.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Once again. To handle API requests you have to build API server first. When you send ajax reqests they must go somewhere, and there must be a program listening requests and doing something what depends on request params and body. The repository you show contains only frontend logic and it is OK because server side logic and front-end can be kept separately and run indepentendly. In the same git account you may find some other reps like this one https://github.com/inci-august/fullstackopen/tree/d6680a40d03536e20ee9537cc64e1cb57dd6b74a/part3/phonebook-backend containing back-end implementation. So you build API server, accepting requests, doing something (create/delete posts, users, auth etc) and sending something back, and AFTER you find it working you can send API requests from frontend. Before front part is created you may use apps like Postman to test your API server.
UPDATE:
You mentioned the following link https://fullstackopen.com/en/part2/altering_data_in_server containing the same I have already said - the server side logic does not suppose to be implemented on this step.

> In the next part of the course we will learn to implement our own
> logic in the backend. We will then take a closer look at tools like
> Postman that helps us to debug our server applications

As for you question - the "props" in requests to server can be sent by params in address string like:

```
axios.delete("api/person/2")
```

In the example above we say to server that we want the person with id=2 to be deleted. On the server side it will be catched with instruction like:

```
router.delete("api/person/:id", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id
  // here you delete the person information and send response back
})
```

ID here will be handled by server as parameter and you will have an access to its value for further actions.

Comment: Hello! I appreciate the effort. I understand that this can be done implementing an API with express for example. But in this case I should use only axios.

This is a course that has several parts. That exercise is from par 2. The APIs are studied on part 3, so I can't use them now.

Take a look!

https://fullstackopen.com/en/#course-contents

The exercise is at the end of part two. Exercise 2.17

https://fullstackopen.com/en/part2/altering_data_in_server

The git commit you posted is likely to be from the part 3.

Thanks for your effort on trying to help me :)

Comment: I have to do something like that

https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2021/04/23/react-axios-http-delete-request-examples

But I have to pass as a prop the id of each object in order to delete a concrete object

Comment: I checked the link and updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

The exercise expected me to remove objects from the json database just using axios. Perhaps I did not express myself clarly enough, but I finally solved it.

I just wanted to pass the id to delete of each object to the axios request.

On the return sttement of App.js, I pass the person object as props to deleteContactOf

```
<ul>
      {contacts.map(person => 
      //Pass all the props from person to Person.js
      //Here you pass the props
          <Person 
          key={person.id} 
          person={person} 
          deleteContact={() => deleteContctOf(person)}
         
          
          />
         
        )}
      </ul>
```

This is how the function deleteContactOf looks like

```
 //Delete contacts
 const deleteContctOf = (person) => {
console.log(person)
  console.log('delete contact ' + person.id + ' ????')

  if (window.confirm("Do you really want to delete this person")) {
  
  contactService
 
  .remove(person.id)
  
 
} else {
  return
}

  

}
```

deleteContactOf passes the id (person.id) to the axios request on file perons.js
Now the id is passed. That's were I was failing.

```
const remove = (id) => {
  const req = axios.delete(`${baseUrl}/${id}`)
  return req.then((res) => res.data)
}
```

Now by clicking the delete button, the contacts that belong to that id are deleted

```
 <button onClick={deleteContact}>Delete</button>
```

Thanks for your time effort. Of course this is implemented with APIs in real life. This was just an specific exercise I had to solve.

Thanks